# is there any way to format d3js graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I have created a graph and it's look tangled

```js
const data ={
    "ok": true,
    "degree": 2,
    "nodes": [
        {
            "id": 19,
            "label": "1",
            "type": "Config"
        },
        {
            "id": 29,
            "label": "2",
            "type": "Model"
        },
        {
            "id": 27,
            "label": "3",
            "type": "Model"
        },
        {
            "id": 24,
            "label": "4",
            "type": "Model"
        },
        {
            "id": 17,
            "label": "5",
            "type": "Component"
        },
        {
            "id": 22,
            "label": "6",
            "type": "Config"
        },
        {
            "id": 21,
            "label": "7",
            "type": "Config"
        },
        {
            "id": 20,
            "label": "8",
            "type": "Config"
        },
        {
            "id": 15,
            "label": "9",
            "type": "Component"
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "label": "10",
            "type": "Technology"
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "label": "11",
            "type": "Technology"
        },
        {
            "id": 13,
            "label": "12",
            "type": "Component"
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "label": "13",
            "type": "Technology"
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "label": "14",
            "type": "Technology"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "label": "15",
            "type": "Technology"
        }
    ],
    "relationships": [
        {
            "id": 40,
            "label": "FRIEND",
            "source": 19,
            "target": 29
        },
        {
            "id": 38,
            "label": "FRIEND",
            "source": 19,
            "target": 27
        },
        {
            "id": 35,
            "label": "FRIEND",
            "source": 19,
            "target": 24
        },
        {
            "id": 24,
            "label": "HAS",
            "source": 19,
            "target": 17
        },
        {
            "id": 33,
            "label": "HAS",
            "source": 22,
            "target": 17
        },
        {
            "id": 30,
            "label": "HAS",
            "source": 21,
            "target": 17
        },
        {
            "id": 27,
            "label": "HAS",
            "source": 20,
            "target": 17
        },
        {
            "id": 23,
            "label": "HAS",
            "source": 19,
            "target": 15
        },
        {
            "id": 29,
            "label": "HAS",
            "source": 21,
            "target": 15
        },
        {
            "id": 17,
            "label": "CONTAINED",
            "source": 15,
            "target": 11
        },
        {
            "id": 16,
            "label": "CONTAINED",
            "source": 15,
            "target": 10
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "label": "INSTALLED_IN",
            "source": 11,
            "target": 15
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "label": "INSTALLED_IN",
            "source": 10,
            "target": 15
        },
        {
            "id": 22,
            "label": "HAS",
            "source": 19,
            "target": 13
        },
        {
            "id": 25,
            "label": "HAS",
            "source": 20,
            "target": 13
        },
        {
            "id": 21,
            "label": "CONTAINED",
            "source": 19,
            "target": 13
        },
        {
            "id": 12,
            "label": "CONTAINED",
            "source": 13,
            "target": 9
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "label": "CONTAINED",
            "source": 13,
            "target": 8
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "label": "CONTAINED",
            "source": 13,
            "target": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "label": "INSTALLED_IN",
            "source": 9,
            "target": 13
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "label": "INSTALLED_IN",
            "source": 8,
            "target": 13
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "label": "INSTALLED_IN",
            "source": 2,
            "target": 13
        }
    ]
}
         const map1 = data.nodes.map(x => x.type);
        const colScale = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10).domain(map1);
       
       const width = 1152;
        const height = 1152;
        let maxLinkOcc = {};
        let linkDistance = 300
        let nodeRadius = 35;
        let lineHeight = 12;

      

        if (data.relationships.length > 0) {
            computeLinkNumber(data.relationships, maxLinkOcc);
        }

        const simulation = d3
            .forceSimulation(data.nodes)
            .force("link", d3.forceLink(data.relationships).id(d => d.id).distance(linkDistance).strength(0.1))
            .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
          
            .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(30).iterations(10))
            .on("tick", ticked);

        const svg = d3.select(".global")
            .append('svg')
            .attr('width', window.innerWidth)
            .attr('height', window.innerHeight)
            .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight])
            .attr("style", "max-width: 100%; height: auto; height: intrinsic;")
            .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
            .attr("font-size", 10)
            .call(d3.zoom().scaleExtent([1 / 2, 8]).on("zoom", zoomed))
            .append("g");

        

        function zoomed(event) {
            svg.attr("transform", event.transform);
        }

        const link = svg.append("g").selectAll("g").data(data.relationships).enter().append("g");

        const paths = link
            .append("path")
            .attr("class", "links")
            .attr("stroke", "#aaa")
            .attr("stroke-width", "3px")
            .attr("id", d => d.id)
            .attr("style", "fill: none;");

        const texts = link.append("text")
            .append("textPath")
            .attr("href", d => "#" + d.id)
            .attr("startOffset", '50%').append("tspan").attr("stroke", "black").attr("font-weight", "bold")
            .attr("style", "text-anchor: middle; font: 10px sans-serif")
            .text(d => d.label + " ►")
            .attr("dy", 3)

        const node = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "nodes")
            .selectAll("g").data(data.nodes)
            .enter().append("g").attr("cursor", "move")
            .call(d3.drag()
                .on("start", dragstarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                .on("end", dragended))

        node.append("circle")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("r", nodeRadius)
            .attr("stroke-width", 3)
            .attr("stroke", (d, _i) => colScale(d.type))
            .attr("fill", (d, _i) => colScale(d.type))
            .on("click", (_e, _data) => {
                console.log("this.state.nodeId", this.state.nodeId, _data.id)
                let num = this.state.nodeId === null ? 0 : 1;
                this.setState((prevState) => ({
                    degree: prevState.nodeId === _data.id ? prevState.degree + 1 : num,
                    nodeId: _data.id
                }
                ), () => {
                    this.nodeSelected(_data, this.state.degree)
                })
            })


        appendText(node, d => d.label, nodeRadius - 10);

        node.selectAll(".fitted-text")
            .attr("fill", "white")
            .selectAll("tspan")
            .attr("font-weight", "bold");


        function computeLinkNumber(links, maxLinkOcc) {
            //sort links by source, then target
            links.sort(linkSort);
            //any links with duplicate source and target get an incremented 'linknum'
            for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
                if (
                    i !== 0 &&
                    links[i].source === links[i - 1].source &&
                    links[i].target === links[i - 1].target
                ) {
                    links[i].linknum = links[i - 1].linknum + 1;
                    maxLinkOcc[links[i].source + "->" + links[i].target] += 1;
                } else {
                    links[i].linknum = 1;
                    maxLinkOcc[links[i].source + "->" + links[i].target] = 1;
                }
            }
        }


        function getLinkPath(source, target, linknum, inv, uniqueLink) {
            let dx = target.x - source.x,
                dy = target.y - source.y,
                dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dx, 2) + Math.pow(dy, 2));

            var c1 = closestPointOnCircleEdge(source, target, nodeRadius);
            var c2 = closestPointOnCircleEdge(target, source, nodeRadius);

            let startX = c1.x,
                startY = c1.y,
                endX = c2.x,
                endY = c2.y,
                centerX = (startX + endX) / 2,
                centerY = (startY + endY) / 2,
                angle = Math.atan2(endY - startY, endX - startX);

            if (uniqueLink) {
                return `M${startX} ${startY} L${endX} ${endY}`;
            }

            let p = Math.max(Math.min(30, 10000 / dist), 25);

            let mx = Math.sin(angle) * (inv * linknum * p) + centerX;
            let my = -Math.cos(angle) * (inv * linknum * p) + centerY;

            return `M${startX} ${startY} C${startX} ${startY}, ${mx} ${my} , ${endX} ${endY}`;
        }


        function linkSort(a, b) {
            if (a.source > b.source) {
                return 1;
            } else if (a.source < b.source) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                if (a.target > b.target) {
                    return 1;
                }
                if (a.target < b.target) {
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }

        function ticked() {
            updateNodes();
            updateLinks();
        }

        function updateNodes() {
            node.attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`);
        }

        function updateLinks(nodeId) {

            let updatedLinks = data.relationships.filter(d =>
                nodeId ? d.source.id === nodeId || d.target.id === nodeId : true
            );

            let linkPath = svg.selectAll(".links").data(updatedLinks, d => d.id);


            linkPath.attr("d", function (d, _i) {

                let linkTspan = d3
                    .select(this.parentNode)
                    .select("textPath")
                    .select("tspan");


                if (d.source.id === d.target.id) {
                    let dr = nodeRadius / 2 + 5 + d.linknum * 7;
                    return (
                        "M" +
                        (d.source.x - 1) +
                        "," +
                        d.source.y +
                        " A " +
                        dr +
                        "," +
                        dr +
                        " 0 1,1 " +
                        (d.target.x + 1) +
                        "," +
                        d.target.y
                    );
                } else {
                    let a1 = maxLinkOcc[d.source.id + "->" + d.target.id];
                    let a2 = maxLinkOcc[d.target.id + "->" + d.source.id];
                    let uniqueLink = a1 + a2 === 1 || (a1 === 1 && !a2);

                    let source = d.source;
                    let target = d.target;

                    if (source.x > target.x) {
                        linkTspan.text(d => "◄ " + d.label);

                        target = d.source;
                        source = d.target;
                        return getLinkPath(source, target, d.linknum, 1, uniqueLink);
                    } else {
                        linkTspan.text(d => d.label + "  ►");
                        return getLinkPath(source, target, d.linknum, -1, uniqueLink);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        function dragstarted(event, d) {
            if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
            d.fx = d.x;
            d.fy = d.y;
        }

        function dragged(event, d) {
            d.fx = event.x;
            d.fy = event.y;
        }

        function dragended(event) {
            if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
        }

        function closestPointOnCircleEdge(A, B, r) {
            const a1 = B.x - A.x;
            const b1 = (B.x - A.x) ** 2 + (B.y - A.y) ** 2;

            let x = A.x + r * (a1 / Math.sqrt(b1));

            const a2 = B.y - A.y;
            const b2 = (B.x - A.x) ** 2 + (B.y - A.y) ** 2;

            let y = A.y + r * (a2 / Math.sqrt(b2));

            return { x, y };
        }


        function appendText(selection, textParam, radiusParam) {
            const getRadius = typeof radiusParam === "function"
                ? radiusParam
                : function () { return radiusParam };

            const getText = typeof textParam === "function"
                ? textParam
                : function () { return textParam };

            selection.each(function (_d) {
                d3.select(this)
                    .selectAll(".fitted-text")
                    .data([{}])
                    .enter()
                    .append("text")
                    .attr("class", "fitted-text").attr("style", "text-anchor: middle; font: 10px sans-serif");
            })

            let text = selection.select(".fitted-text");

            text.datum(function (d) {
                var lines = getLines(getText(d));
                d.lines = lines.lines;
                d.textRadius = lines.textRadius;
                return d
            });

            text.selectAll("tspan")
                .data((d) => d.lines)
                .enter()
                .append("tspan")
                .attr("x", 0)
                .attr("y", (d, i) => (i - d.linesLength / 2 + 0.8) * lineHeight)
                .text((d) => d.text);

            text.attr("transform", function (d) {
                var scale = 1;
                if (d.textRadius !== 0 && d.textRadius) {
                    scale = getRadius(d) / d.textRadius;
                }
                return "translate(" + 0 + "," + 0 + ")" + " scale(" + scale + ")"
            });
        }

        function getLines(text) {
            if (text === undefined || text === null) {
                return { lines: [] }
            }

            text = String(text);

            let words = text.split(/\s+/g); // To hyphenate: /\s+|(?<=-)/
            if (!words[words.length - 1]) words.pop();
            if (!words[0]) words.shift();
            let targetWidth = Math.sqrt(measureWidth(text.trim()) * lineHeight);
            let line;
            let lineWidth0 = Infinity;
            let lines = [];

            for (let i = 0, n = words.length; i < n; ++i) {
                let lineText1 = (line ? line.text + " " : "") + words[i];
                let lineWidth1 = measureWidth(lineText1);
                if ((lineWidth0 + lineWidth1) / 2 < targetWidth) {
                    line.width = lineWidth0 = lineWidth1;
                    line.text = lineText1;
                } else {
                    lineWidth0 = measureWidth(words[i]);
                    line = { width: lineWidth0, text: words[i] };
                    lines.push(line);
                }
            }

            let textRadius = 0;
            for (let i = 0, n = lines.length; i < n; ++i) {
                let dy = (Math.abs(i - n / 2 + 0.5) + 0.5) * lineHeight
                let dx = lines[i].width / 2;
                textRadius = Math.max(textRadius, Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy));
            }

            return {
                "lines": lines.map(function (d) {
                    return { "text": d.text, "linesLength": lines.length }
                }),
                "textRadius": textRadius
            }
        }

        function measureWidth(text) {
            const context = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d")
            return context.measureText(text).width;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div class="global" style="display: "inline-block"; position: "relative"; width: "100%"; "verticalAlign": "top"; overflow: "hidden""> </div>
      
   </body>
</html>
```

But I want to format this graph like this any lead
I also go through https://github.com/d3/d3-force documentation but I didn't get it
Thank you so much

[image]

Comment: Your snippet doesn't work...

Comment: it is working you need to scroll to view the result, I means you need to pull upside using mouse and then you can see